# Why doesn't AngularJS update the views for model containers?

Tags: angularjs

In the following Angular application, why don't `{{myForm}}` and `{{myForm.userTypeInput}}` update when the `userTypeInput` model is changed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Ctrl($scope) {
            $scope.userType = 'guest';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    userType: <input name="userTypeInput" ng-model="userType">

    <tt>userType = {{userType}}</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm = {{myForm}}</tt><br>
    <tt>myForm.userTypeInput = {{myForm.userTypeInput}}</tt><br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The first line updates according to the changes made in the model, but the last couple of lines always remain the same:

```
myForm = {"userTypeInput":{}}
myForm.userTypeInput = {}
```

while I expected them to change according to the value I type in `userTypeInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute of the element does nothing in terms of how angular treats a DOM element, the ng-model, ng-app, and ng-controller are the only parts in your HTML (along with the data bindings) that Angular will recognize.  Since angular doesn't look at the name attribute when resolving variables for binding it doesn't update the other two, Angular is only looking at variables on the scope.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it was binding the entire scope, not just what I explicitly declared as model.

Comment: It is binding to the objects referred to in the scope but there's the DOM hierarchy and then there's the Angular scope hierarchy and though they are related they don't contain the same information.  You can have your own elements or attributes that you write directive code for and that could bind things from the DOM elements to the scope as ng-model does, but the HTML name attribute by default doesn't affect the angular scope.

Comment: To clarify a bit ng-model basically makes adds a listener or "binds" to the event for changes for whatever the input type is.  Then when the change event happens it will update the property referred to by the current Angular scope that has the name of whatever was in the quotes.  ie ng-model='myProperty' means if this input changes update myProperty referred to by the current scope, also if myProperty changes update the value of this input (two way binding).